# Resetting scale after zooming on iPad/iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, zooming, scale, viewport

In my app I enable and disable zoom for certain sections

I enable zoom with

```
$('head meta[name=viewport]').remove();
$('head').prepend('<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, width=device-width,    minimum-scale=1.0 , initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=5.0" />');
```

when I leave the zoom able section I disable zoom

```
$('head meta[name=viewport]').remove();
$('head').prepend('<meta name="viewport" id="testViewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0 , initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />');
```

The problem is , if I have zoomed in , then exit... the page stays stuck in the zoomable state

Is it possible to reset the page scale , then lock the zooming using jquery ?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and could not find any answers online. The solution I decided to go with was doing a quick page refresh after users clicked out of the zoomable area. It helped that my only zoomable content was in a lightbox, so the closing of the lightbox coincided with the quick refresh of the page, which reset the page scale back to where I wanted.

So, on lightbox close, I fire off: `

- location.reload();`

Once the page refreshes, the user was taken back to where they were browsing in the content, and user experience resumed with the page scale I was trying to achieve. I hope that gives you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

my solution is to memorize ratio before scale is change and then zoom it with viewport by memorized ratio.
On iOS7 zoom by viewport doesnt work always. So I use location.reload(false); (how Jason wrote)

Answer (score -1):

```
//prevent zoom
$('meta[name=viewport]').remove();
$('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">');

//enable zoom
$('meta[name=viewport]').remove();
$('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=yes">' );

//reset zoom use all together in function
$('meta[name=viewport]').remove();
$('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">');
$('meta[name=viewport]').remove();
$('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=yes">' );
```